# get generic type from object list java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I had custom converter for dozer framework

constom converter called for generic type list source and generic type list destination

```
public class ListCommonCustomConverter implements ConfigurableCustomConverter{
  public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass) {
    log.info("Inside CommonCustomConverter :: convert");
    // Need to fine generic type of list
    return null;
  }
}
```

Eg: if `List<Person>` passed as destination for converter i need to get Person class from destination object inside converter method.

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could get type info from a generic type by calling `getClass().getGenericInterfaces()` if your class was declared like:

```
public class ListCommonCustomConverter implements ConfigurableCustomConverter<Person>
```

But since this converter is not parameterized, you could do a trick:

```
public interface CustomConverterWithTypeInfo<T> extends ConfigurableCustomConverter{
}


public class ListCommonCustomConverter implements CustomConverterWithTypeInfo<Person>{
    public Object convert(Object destination, Object source, Class<?> destinationClass, Class<?> sourceClass) {
        Class<?> myClass = (Class)((ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        //...
    }
}
```

Or you could simply do:

```
List<?> list = (List)destination;
if(!list.isEmpty()){
     Class<?> myClass = list.get(0).getClass();
}
```